# TypeError: Object of type uint8 is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

I'm having some problems with dumping a dictionary to a json file. The dictionary is made up of color tuples/values from an image, and is generated like so:

```
import cv2, json

img = cv2.imread("bg.png")
HEIGHT, WIDTH = img.shape[:2]

colors = set({})
col_dict = {}
index = 0

for h in range(HEIGHT):
    for w in range(WIDTH):
        if tuple(img[h, w]) in colors:
            continue
        else:
            colors.add(tuple(img[h, w]))
            col_dict[str(index)] = list(img[h, w])
            index += 1
```

The following loop will extract all the different types of color values in an image and stores them in the dictionary, using the `index` variable as the key. The `colors` set variable is used in another part of my program, so it can be ignored.

The loop successfully creates a dictionary, but when executing the following code:

```
with open("file.json", "w") as infile:
    json.dump(col_dict, infile, indent=2)
```

The following error is produced:

```
TypeError: Object of type uint8 is not JSON serializable
```

The code works when I define a dictionary and it's values manually, like so:

```
colors = {
    "0" : (109, 87, 34),
    "1" : (209, 87, 34),
    "2" : (85, 98, 34), ...}

with open("file.json", "w") as infile:
    json.dump(colors, infile)
```

I have no idea why it isn't working now, it still works for other programs that do the same thing.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check/print the type of `img[h, w]` where you do `col_dict[str(index)] = list(img[h, w])`.

Comment: @Matthias I've tested it and it returns a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem with the code. CV2 image objects are `numpy.ndarrays`, and each pixel color value is a `numpy.uint8` data type. Since json files do not understand numpy uint8 integers, it produced the error `TypeError: Object of type uint8 is not JSON serializable`.

Here is the solution to my code:

```
import cv2, json

img = cv2.imread("bg.png")
HEIGHT, WIDTH = img.shape[:2]

colors = set({})
col_dict = {}
index = 0

for h in range(HEIGHT):
    for w in range(WIDTH):
        if tuple(img[h, w]) in colors:
            continue
        else:
            value = (int(img[h, w][0]), int(img[h, w][1]), int(img[h, w][2]))  # This converts each BGR value from uint8 to int.
            colors.add(tuple(img[h, w]))
            col_dict[str(index)] = value
            index += 1

with open("file.json", "w") as infile:
    json.dump(col_dict, infile, indent=2)
```

All I needed to do was convert the numpy uint8 object to a python integer.